# What is the difference between a relationship with total participation and an identifying relationship?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, rdbms, entity-relationship

I've read in both the case of a relationship with total participation and the case of an identifying relationship that one entity does not exist without the other.

I've also read, 'Not every total participation means an identifying relationship'.

What is the difference between them?

Comment: You've read some stuff. What are *definitions* for those terms?

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking at relationships from a participation point of view then, there exists participation constraint that specifies whether the existence of an entity type (say A) depends on its being related to another entity type (say B) via the relationship type.

This constraint specifies the minimum number of relationship instances that each entity can participate in, and is sometimes called the minimum cardinality constraint. There are two types of participation constraints—**total** and **partial**.

The famous employee example:
"***every*** employee *must work* for a department."

- Entity Type A: EMPLOYEE
- Entity Type B: DEPARTMENT
- Relationship : WORKS_FOR

That is: an employee entity can exist only if it participates in at least one WORKS_FOR relationship instance.

Thus, the participation of EMPLOYEE in WORKS_FOR is called **total participation** (a.k.a **existence dependency**), meaning that *every* entity in the total set of employee entities must be related to *a* department entity via WORKS_FOR

Now partial relationship is self explanatory after the above example.

Coming to Identifying Relationships, we first need to be familiar with weak entity types:

> Entity types that do not have key attributes of their own are called
> weak entity types.

Thus these are identified by being related to specific entities from *another entity type* in combination with one of their attribute values.

We call this *other entity type* the **identifying (** or **owner ) entity type** and we call the relationship type that relates a weak entity type to its owner the **identifying relationship** of the weak entity type.

#### *The crux:*

A weak entity type always has a total participation constraint (existence
dependency) with respect to its identifying relationship because a weak entity cannot be identified without an owner entity.

However, not every existence dependency results in a weak entity type. As in above example, the EMPLOYEE entity type cannot exist unless it is related to a DEPARTMENT entity type, even though it has its own key (Employee_ID) and hence is not a weak entity.

Thus for Identifying relationship a weak entity is a must (thus has total participation implicitly) however a total participation does not imply identifying relationship as it may not have weak entity as described in above examples.

Hope it helped, if you have any arguments feel free to comment.

> All references from:
>
> Fundamentals Of Database Systems (6th Edition)
>
> Ramez Elmasri, Shamkant B. Navathe [ISBN 13: 978-0-136-08620-8]

Answer (score 1):

Your attempts at definitions are too fuzzy to be useful.

Of course any entity must exist in order to participate in a relationship, and the entity or entities it participates with must exist. Don't confuse this with an entity type needing another entity type to exist.

A first entity type *totally participates* in a relationship with a second when every entity of the first type must participate. Total participation of a type can be 1:1, many:1 or many:many. Dropping the relationship or its totality might give a design where the previously totally participating entities still exist, possibly participating in other relationships.

A *distinguishing relationship* is one between a first/child entity type and a second/parent entity type whose primary key is included in the primary key of the first/child. A consequence is that child entities participate totally in the identifying relationship. Total participation of the child type is 1:1 or many:1. Dropping the totality or the relationship requires dropping the child entity type and any other relationships it participates in.

If we don't change correspondences between primary keys & entities then as long as a child entity exists it is associated with the same parent entity. Whereas some non-identifying relationship could have associations come and go as long as every entity of a totally participating type participates at least once.

ER modeling is rather arbitrary. Any identifying relationship & its child entity type could be set up instead as a total many:1 non-participating relationship. But that design wouldn't make the existence-dependence of the child type on the parent type explicit.